# How can i implement ServletContextAware interface in struts 1.3.10?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, struts-1

Am developing web application using struts 1.3.10 framework.

so, i will manage session in whole application(across all jsp pages and action class also), then i was searching session management in struts 1.3.10 but i got session management for struts2 application by using Aware interfaces.

If it possible, how to implement servletcontextaware interface in STRUTS 1.3.10 (or) any other way to implement session for whole application by using struts 1.3.10..........

Thanks in advance.

Comment: upgrade to struts2, struts1 is officially deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I used a filter to access the session for the security across my app.

In web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFiltrer</filter-name>
    <filter-class>app.filtrer.SecurityFiltrer</filter-class>
</filter>
```

SecurityFilter.java :

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter  {

    public SecurityFilter() {
        super();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

            // DO YOUR STUFF HERE

    }
}
```